# How do I use an Ansible list to remove a list of files?

Tags: loops, automation, ansible

I am trying to use Ansible to delete files from an Ansible list. I want to iterate through that list and remove files beginning with the string stored in each element. Here's what I have:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    regexp: '(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\-[0-9])'
    empty: [null]
  tasks:    
    # Select only the part of each file path in the list that I need (the beginning). 
    - set_fact: matches="{{ unarchived_list.files | map('regex_search', regexp) | list|difference(empty) }}"
    
    - debug: msg="{{ matches }}"

    - name: Delete files starting with each element of matches.
      file:
        path: "/var/tmp/MyFile/{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ matches }}"
```

This is able to delete files that match each element, but only if it's an exact match. Basically I'm trying to   do the equivalent of:

```
for file in "${fileList[@]}"; do
   rm file*
done
```

I've been using Ansible for while now but I'm new to Ansible loops.

Comment: See [mre]. [edit] the question and remove the zip story. Focus on the list and regex. Post a list, a regex, and a result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If `unarchived_list.files` is a simple list, you can filter the entries of this list as follows:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    matches: "{{ unarchived_list.files | select('search', regexp) | list }}"
```

If you need case insensitive matching, you can add `ignorecase=true` parameter:
`select('search', regexp, 'ignorecase=true')`

Ansible documentation: [`search` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)